# Direct client access to Cloud Storage private asset

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Perhaps you can help us to understand how I can solve my problem :

Our web application uses Street View API for custom navigation, so it needs to display panoramic pictures from Google Storage directly into the client.
These pictures are to be private, so URL should be like this :

> https://storage.cloud.google.com/*bucket/panoramic_tile-zoom-x-y.jpg*

and these assets are called by the Street View API function.

This URI is not the direct link to the asset, but the response is an HMTL type, a form redirecting to a temporary URL :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2013 09:16:46 GMT
Expires: Wed, 20 Nov 2013 09:16:46 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 2341
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic

<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://doc-15fdi-03uv6-s-googleusercontent.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gs/a...pwZw" id="redirectForm">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="13668820...pj1onfrc2gvdfrp"> 
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="AGjQbs4J...b1PUgwjq4O-B7MfcD3fVpo5WrOw">
</form> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using AJAX again to retrieve the image asset, for each tile of the panoramic view could be performed but would likely to slow down performance of the website.

Comparatively, if assets are public, displaying the pictures is straightforward.

Do you know a way to request private GS asset with fixed URLs?

Thank you for your time.

Jeremie

Comment: Have you looked at [signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) ?

Comment: Yes, and it works now.

Comment: Yes, following your advice it works now. With respects to the number of tiles to display for a panorama image, there is a lot of signing URLs request to be done, slowing done the performance. The average request waiting time is 400ms for a tile, compare to 100ms for a Google's Street View tile. Jeremie